# Wizard page resize

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm developing a application which has a multi-page wizard. And we want it to perform like the Preferences page in Eclipse. When you are dragging the left side, only the right side will be resized. 
The below shows the BasePage of the wizard. Each page in this wizard extends this BasePage. How can I modify the BasePage?

```
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class BasePage extends WizardPage 
{   
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    //Color blue = SWTResourceManager.getColor(65, 105, 225);
    //Color black = SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 0, 0);
    //Button rbtnIntroduce; 
    Button rbtnSourcedb;
    Button rbtnTargetdb;
    Button rbtnDatatype;
    Button rbtnSelectObjects;
    Button rbtnMigrate;
    Composite compositeContent;
    SashForm sashContainer;

    public BasePage(String name) 
    {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) 
    {
        log.debug("BasePage.createControl");

        sashContainer = new SashForm(parent, SWT.NONE);
        setControl(sashContainer);// must set control for wizard page

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        sashContainer.setLayout(layout);        

        Composite compositeNavigator = new Composite(sashContainer, SWT.BORDER);

        /*
        rbtnIntroduce = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        //rbtnIntroduce.setForeground(blue);
        rbtnIntroduce.setBounds(10, 10, 110, 20);
        rbtnIntroduce.setText("Introduce");
        */

        rbtnTargetdb = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtnTargetdb.setBounds(10, 35, 110, 20);
        rbtnTargetdb.setText("Target DB");

        rbtnSourcedb = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtnSourcedb.setBounds(10, 60, 110, 20);
        rbtnSourcedb.setText("Source DB");

        rbtnDatatype = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtnDatatype.setBounds(10, 110, 110, 20);
        rbtnDatatype.setText("Datatype Cast");

        rbtnSelectObjects = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtnSelectObjects.setBounds(10, 85, 110, 20);
        rbtnSelectObjects.setText("Object Choose");

        rbtnMigrate = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtnMigrate.setBounds(10, 135, 110, 20);
        rbtnMigrate.setText("Migrate"); 

        compositeContent = new Composite(sashContainer, SWT.NONE);      
        sashContainer.setWeights(new int[] { 1, 3 });
    }

    /*
    private Button getRadioButton(Composite compositeNavigator, String name)
    {
        Button rbtn = new Button(compositeNavigator, SWT.RADIO);
        rbtn.setText(name);
        return rbtn;
    }
    */

    void updatePage(Button btn)
    {
        /*
        rbtnIntroduce.setSelection(rbtnIntroduce==btn);
        rbtnIntroduce.setEnabled(rbtnIntroduce==btn);
        //rbtnIntroduce.setForeground(rbtnIntroduce==btn? blue:black);
        */

        rbtnTargetdb.setSelection(rbtnTargetdb==btn);
        rbtnTargetdb.setEnabled(rbtnTargetdb==btn);
        //rbtnTargetdb.setForeground(rbtnTargetdb==btn? blue:black);

        rbtnSourcedb.setSelection(rbtnSourcedb==btn);
        rbtnSourcedb.setEnabled(rbtnSourcedb==btn);
        //rbtnSourcedb.setForeground(rbtnSourcedb==btn? blue:black);

        rbtnTargetdb.setSelection(rbtnTargetdb==btn);
        rbtnTargetdb.setEnabled(rbtnTargetdb==btn);
        //rbtnTargetdb.setForeground(rbtnTargetdb==btn? blue:black);

        rbtnDatatype.setSelection(rbtnDatatype==btn);
        rbtnDatatype.setEnabled(rbtnDatatype==btn);
        //rbtnDatatype.setForeground(rbtnDatatype==btn? blue:black);

        rbtnSelectObjects.setSelection(rbtnSelectObjects==btn);
        rbtnSelectObjects.setEnabled(rbtnSelectObjects==btn);
        //rbtnSelectObjects.setForeground(rbtnSelectObjects==btn? blue:black);

        rbtnMigrate.setSelection(rbtnMigrate==btn);
        rbtnMigrate.setEnabled(rbtnMigrate==btn);
        //rbtnMigrate.setForeground(rbtnMigrate==btn? blue:black);      
    }

}
```

Comment: The preference dialog doesn't use `SashForm` - I don't think you can do this with `SashForm`. `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog` does this using a `Sash` and some rather complex code - look at its `createSash` method.

Comment: Thanks, greg. I think the createSash method is quite complex.  I found a simple method to use a sashForm with a controlListener, which can set a fixed size and a variable size of the sashForm. It solved the problem.